# Perform 3 tasks in a single api call

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

My current api call flow from my client is as follows:

1. Send data to brand endpoint, retrieve recently inserted id, assign to userData.brand
2. Send data to user endpoint, retrieve recently inserted id, assign to userData.user
3. Send both values to userBrand endpoint

This seems like a costly process, so I am thinking of consolidating all the requests into one, but I am not sure how to process it from the server side. I know that I can just use one endpoint, but I don't know to how to use all the serializers/views against one endpoint.

**So on the client side, this is what I have:**

In *brand.js*

```
  AdsomaService.registerUser(vm.userData).then(function(data) {
    vm.successMessage = data.message;
    vm.userBrandData.user = data.id;
  }, function error(data) {
    $log.info(data);
    vm.errorMessage = data;
    errorCount++;
  });          

  AdsomaService.registerUserBrand(vm.userBrandData).then(function(data) {
    vm.successMessage = data.message;
  }, function error(data) {
    $log.info(data);
    vm.errorMessage = data;
    errorCount++;
  });   

  if(errorCount > 0) {
    vm.message = vm.errorMessage;
    angular.element('#errorMessage').appendTo('body').modal('show');
  } else if(errorCount === 0) {
    vm.message = vm.successMessage;
    angular.element('#successMessage').appendTo('body').modal('show');
  }
```

In *adsoma.js*

```
function registerUser(userData) {
  var url = envService.read('apiUrl') + '/user_signup/';
  var dataJSON = {
    email: userData.email,
    password: userData.password,
    account_type: userData.accountType
  };
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(dataJSON)
  };
  return ($http(req).then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}

function registerBrand(brandData) {
  var url = envService.read('apiUrl') + '/brand_signup/';
  var dataJSON = {
    name: brandData.name,
    brand: brandData.name,
    email: brandData.email,
    phone: brandData.phone,
    website: brandData.website
  };
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(dataJSON)
  };
  return ($http(req).then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}

function registerUserBrand(userData) {
  var url = envService.read('apiUrl') + '/user_brand_signup/';
    var dataJSON = {
    user: userData.user,
    brand: userData.brand
  };
  $log.info(dataJSON);
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(dataJSON)
  };
  return ($http(req).then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

**And on the server side, this is what I have:**

In *views.py*

Code here: https://pastebin.com/P5ih75An.

In *serialisers.py*

Code here: https://pastebin.com/2zDgZDLc.

Comment: How often does this process run? Seems like if it is a registration process it doesn't have a significant impact to make several requests once then done. Would be different if it was numerous requests repeated in an interval

Comment: We are still developing the system. But the issue is that sometimes with the back/forth interaction, we don't receive an id in steps 1 & 2, so step 3 breaks. What we are also noticing is that the id we are receiving is in fact for the previous record, so steps 1 & 2 work as expected, but the record posted in step 3 references the previous user/brand object instead of the current one. So there seems to be some type of lag.

Comment: `if(errorCount > 0)` runs before prior requests complete since they are *asynchronous* . Try `$q.all([requestPromise2, requestPromise1]).then(function(){ /* check error counts */})`

Comment: Not seeing where you make third request but is likely related to same issue as your error count test and can probably solve same as above comment